# my php code is displayed as it is in the browser not executed

Tags: php, wamp

my php code is not executed and is displayed as it is in the browser.
I used the `.php` extension to save the file.

I am using WAMP Server.

Please also note that other php files are working which shows that php is installed and configured properly.

The code I am using:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$un=$_POST['un'];
$pw=$_POST['pw'];
$ei=$_POST['ei'];

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root');
mysqli_select_db($con,'login');
$q=" INSERT INTO user (name, username, password) value('$name','$un,'$pw')";  
mysqli_query($con,$q);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please show us your code, we can't help you otherwise.

Comment: <?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$un=$_POST['un'];
$pw=$_POST['pw'];
$ei=$_POST['ei'];


$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root');
mysqli_select_db($con,'login');
$q=" INSERT INTO user (name, username, password) value('$name','$un,'$pw')";
mysqli_query($con,$q);
mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: By show us your code, I never meant chuck it in a comment, I meant format and place it in your post...

Comment: i dont think code is the problem......still i uploaded it

Comment: You have a lot of issues in your code, use prepared statements rather than directly passing variables, do proper form validation and ensure your queries/connection is successful.

Comment: but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I never said it would, I was merely making an observation/suggestions for when it does start working.

Comment: ohk... thanks for the suggestion i will improve my code if it "worked".

Comment: are you using `file:///` instead of `http://localhost` ?

Comment: yes, this is how it looks file:///C:/wamp64/www/login/signupdb.php

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are some configuration issues. Follow these steps

**1-** Check if PHP is installed and running.

**2-** Also check if you are using short tags `<?` or not as they are deprecated and now 
`<?php` is used Double check your file extension.

**3-** Make sure you are saving it as .php and not just renaming it as .php

**4-** Check Apache httpd.conf file for PHP module

**5-** Check Apache httpd.conf file for PHP mime type in it

Comment: This could definitely be comment.

Comment: php is installed other codes are working..... and used <?php  //code     ?>

Comment: checked file type is also php, cheked apache